# Clear screen in C

Tags: c, visual-studio

I am new to programming, and so I do encounter basic issues. In the program I am building, I need to clear the screen at a certain point, but it does not accept `clrscr();` or `system("cls");` what are other options available?? I have included `stdio.h` & `conio.h`.
If it helps, the compiler I am using is Visual studio 2010.

Comment: Using `system("cls")` should actually do it. What happens when you try that? What do you mean by "it does not accept..."? What is "it"?

Comment: system() is defined in windows.h.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio removed "common" conio.h functions, like clear screen, a long time ago.

system() is in stdlib.h if you want to use it.

However, if you want to do serious terminal output on Windows, check out something like this: http://www.projectpluto.com/win32a.htm

Comment: [`system()` is actually declared in `<stdlib.h>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/277bwbdz(v=vs.71).aspx). It is not a Win32 API function.

Comment: @GregHewgill as you will, MSDN says it is in fact there.

Answer (score 0):

You, should use stdlib.h library file to get the clear screen command. And also the command for clearing the screen in c/c++ in visual studio is

```
#include <stdlib.h>

system ("cls");
```